# Can a mSATA SSD have a fake capacity

Tags: ssd, msata

I've heard of USB devices having their firmware rewritten to show that the drives are bigger than what their actual capacity is, but can this happen to a mSATA SSD? The device is an unmarked "Wave" SSD, but I don't want to install it unless I know that its capacity is indeed 256GB

Comment: Yup, anything that's counterfeit can be made to appear to be something it's not. That includes SSDs, USB keys, RAM, anything. Buying from reputable dealers minimizes your chance of getting a fake.

Comment: I just bought a 128gb Lite-on mSATA SSD with what looks like a legit manufacturer's label but plugging it in revealed that it is only 64gb.  Why someone would go through all of the trouble to counterfeit an ssd to still work but be a different capacity, I can't figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can re-write firmware, then yes you can report anything you want. The only way to verify the capacity is to write data to the entire drive, read it back, and verify that the data returned match the data written.